# Homotopy invariance of $K_0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-k-theory

It is well-known that algebraic $K$-theory is $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant for regular Noetherian schemes. The way this is proved is usually to prove that $K$-theory of coherent sheaves i.e. $G$-theory matches with the $K$-theory of vector bundles. Then $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariance is proved for $G$-theory using the localization sequence. Now let's consider the case of $K_0$. I was wondering since this proof relies on higher $K$-theory, is it possible to give a proof of $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariance of $K_0$ by just the relations coming from the definition of $K_0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will use capital letters to denote $R[t]$ modules and capital letters subscripted with $0$ to denote $R$ modules.  All rings are assumed noetherian and all modules are assumed finitely generated.  The key lemma is due to Swan:

**Lemma**: Let $M\subset N_0[t]$.  Then there exists a short exact sequence of the form
$$0\rightarrow X_0[t]\rightarrow Y_0[t]\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$$.

**Sketch of Proof**:  Let $N_k$ be the $R$-module $\sum_{i=0}^k (t^i)N_0$.  Let $M_k=M\cap N_k$.  Take $k$ large enough so that $M_k$ contains a generating set for $M$ over $R[t]$.  Let $X_0=M_k$ and $Y_0=M_{k+1}$.  Map $Y_0[t]$ to $M$ in the obvious way.  Check that this works.

**Corollary**:  If $R$ is regular and $M$ is an $R[t]$ module then $M$ has a finite projective resolution of the form
$$0\rightarrow X^n_0[t]\rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow X^1_0[t]\rightarrow X^0_0[t]\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$$

**Sketch of Proof:**  Map a free $R[t]$-module onto $M$ and let $M'$ be the kernel. It suffices to prove the corollary for $M'$.   Apply the lemma to $M'$ to get a sequence
$$0\rightarrow X_0[t]\rightarrow Y_0[t]\rightarrow M'\rightarrow 0$$
Take finite projective $R$-resolutions of $X_0$ and $Y_0$, extend them to finite projective $R[t]$-resolutions of $X_0[t]$ and $Y_0[t]$, and then use the mapping cone construction to get the desired resolution of $M'$.

**Theorem:** If $R$ is regular, then $K_0(R)\rightarrow K_0(R[t])$ is an isomorphism.

**Proof:**Injectivity  is clear because the map splits.  For surjectivity, take $M$ projective over $R[t]$ and use the lemma to represent its $K_0$ class as an alternating sum of $[X_i[t]]$ where all the $X_i$ are projective over $R$.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answer. May I ask what references these belong to?

Comment: I learned this argument in graduate school from Dick Swan, and amazingly enough I remember it.  I'm not sure where (if at all) to find it in print.   Note that it also gives an independent proof that if $R$ is regular, so is $R[t]$.

Comment: I had a somewhat similar question but it might be much harder. For split exact categories $K_1$ is given by Bass' $K_1$, which it is generated by $(P,\alpha)$, where $P$ is an object of the category and $\alpha$ is an automorphism, subject to relations I)$(P,\alpha_1\circ \alpha_2)=(P, \alpha_1)+(P,\alpha_2)$ and II) $(P,id)=0$. Now if we want to prove homotopy invariance for $K_1$ it is not hard to see we can ignore relations II (the subgroup related to relations II split injects into the group with only relations I).

Comment: So it becomes relevant to ask whether it is possible in the resolution by extended bundles in your answer (probably a slightly modified one), is it possible to lift morphisms for example automorphisms in a way that are extended morphisms of the extended bundles? (I forgot to add the relations coming from short exact sequences.)

Comment: @user127776:  I will try to find time to think about this.  But Bass must have proved the $K_1$ case without using higher $K$-theory, so maybe the first question is:  How did Bass do it?